# HmacSHA1 two equal instance

Tags: java, hmacsha1

I need to implement two `HmacSHA1` Class cipher in `java 8` when I use the same key,because if I use the below code on the same string with the same key the digest that I get it's different. 
I have to check `digest` after that client has sent the `key` to the `server`. 
How can I do it?

```
public class HmacSha1  implements Serializable{
    private SecretKey key;
    Mac m;
    public HmacSha1(SecretKey key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
        this.key=key;
        m=Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");

    }

    public byte[] hashing(byte[] data) throws InvalidKeyException
    {
        m.init(key);
        byte[] encr=m.doFinal(data);
        return encr;
    }



}
```

Yes, I can.

An Android Client Generate key so:

```
SecretKey kg=KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        kg.init(160);
        keyHmac=kg.generateKey();

HmacSha1 algHMacAndroid = new HmacSha1(keyHmac);
```

And sends it like keyMac.getEncoded() to Server java 8 that creates

```
SecretKey keyHmac=new SecretKeySpec(algKey,"HmacSHA1");
 and
HmacSha1 algHmacJava =new HmacSha1(keyHmac) ;
```

The key are the same I have checked them.

Android generates digest:

```
algHmacAndroid.hashing("Android String".getBytes());
```

and 
Sever java does the same thing:

```
algHmacJava.hashing("Android String".getBytes());
```

I compare and convert the result in Base64, the string is different.

Comment: Please post your conditional checks ..What you exactly trying to compare.. @enjoytech

Comment: If I calculate Hmac (using your implementation too) over the same String! (I mean byte[]) using the same key I get the same digest.  Can you share  your code where  HmacSha1 gets called?

Comment: converting String to bytes can be problematic if the encoding is different between server and client. change it to *"Android String".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));*

Comment: Nothing, I tried but without result, your solution doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I solve it, when I send key among Activity, the key changes. Thanks you anyway

Comment: remove "solved" from title -> if it is solved, mark the correct answer of post yours

Comment: How Can I mark as solved my post??